# Disabling Alt hotkey from selecting menuStrip

Tags: c#

So I have shortcuts set up for alt and other buttons to insert text into a `textbox`. But whenever I hit alt it selects my `menuStrip` and selects a menuItem with a letter closest to that being pressed by my keyboard.

I tried:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Alt)
{
    handled = true;
}
```

as shown in [this tutorial](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2ab80876-b3cf-4ea8-bd03-40511cc819c0/how-to-disable-spacebar-from-activating-button) but it throws me an error saying handled doesn't exist.

Comment: The tutorial says to *Make a local boolean variable on your form named "handled".* have you done this?

Comment: I did that but it doesn't change anything it just makes a random bool true. I need it to stop selecting the menuStrip

Comment: What you're doing seems a little different to the tutorial. As a starting point, have you tried swallowing the alt key push by setting e.Handled = true ?

Comment: You need to set 'e.handled' (not just 'handled') to pass the information back to the caller of your event.

Comment: How did you setup those hotkeys?

Answer (score 3):

```
Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
    {
     if (e.Alt)
       {
            e.Handled = false;
       }
    }
```

try using the KeyDown Event.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the KeyDown event first:

```
        KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
```

In this event handler, set the Handled property on the second parameter to true when one of the ALT keys is pressed.

```
    void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.System && (e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt || e.SystemKey == Key.RightAlt))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```